# Discord.js option types

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord, discord.js

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to figure out which option types work apart from string.

my code:

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "test",
    description: "mention a user",
    type: 'CHAT_INPUT',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'user',
            description: 'mentions a user',
            type: 'User',
            required: 'true'
        }
    ],
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
        interaction.followUp('yes');
    },
};
```

and once ran I receive a long error with the message being: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
3.options[0]: Field "type" is required to determine the model type.
I know this has nothing to do with my handler since everything else operates fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `type` equals `6`. As mentioned in the Discord documentation, option types should be numbers.

```
SUB_COMMAND 1   
SUB_COMMAND_GROUP 2 
STRING 3    
INTEGER 4
BOOLEAN 5   
USER 6  
CHANNEL 7
ROLE 8  
MENTIONABLE 9
NUMBER 10
ATTACHMENT 11
```

Implemented using your code:

```
const { Client, CommandInteraction } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: "test",
    description: "mention a user",
    type: 'CHAT_INPUT',
    options: [
        {
            name: 'user',
            description: 'mentions a user',
            type: 6,
            required: 'true'
        }
    ],
    /**
     *
     * @param {Client} client
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
     * @param {String[]} args
     */
    run: async (client, interaction, args) => {
        interaction.followUp('yes');
    },
};
```